# bubbling animation in algorithm visualizer

Tags: javascript, algorithm, react-native

```js
  state={
    array: [],
    sorted: false,
  };

  sort() {
    var swapped;
    var array = this.state.array;
    do {
        swapped = false;
        for (var i=0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
                var temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i+1];
                array[i+1] = temp;
                this.setState({ array });
                console.log(array);
                swapped=true;
            }
        }
    } while (swapped);
  }

  renderBars() {
    return this.state.array.map(listValue => (
      <View key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000) + 1}>
        <Text>{listValue}</Text>
        <View style={{ width: 15, height: (listValue * 30), backgroundColor: '#3F51B5', borderRadius: 4 }} />
      </View>
    ));
  }
```

The above code isn't rerendering during every state change. I wish to achieve a bubbling animation for bubble sort like an algorithm visualizer but the view is only rerendering at the end and not at every state change.

Comment: you'll have better result with `Animated.View` around 60 fps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's fine, it's just rendering too quickly. The version below illustrates with a 3 second sleep so you can see each step rendered.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state={
      array: [4,3,2,1],
      sorted: false,
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.sort();
  }

  async sort() {
    var swapped;
    var array = this.state.array;
    do {
      swapped = false;
      for (var i=0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i+1]) {
          var temp = array[i];
          array[i] = array[i+1];
          array[i+1] = temp;
          this.setState({ array });
          console.log(array);
          await this.sleep(3000);
          swapped=true;
        }
      }
    } while (swapped);
  }

  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.array.map(listValue => (
        <View key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000) + 1}>
          <Text>{listValue}</Text>
          <View style={{ width: 15, height: (listValue * 30), backgroundColor: '#3F51B5', borderRadius: 4 }} />
        </View>
    ));
  }
}

export default App;
```

EDIT - @Val is correct. It’s better to switch to Animated.View

Answer (score 0):

React batches setState calls into one setState call for performance reasons.  You are calling setState in a loop and it is batching the calls.  You could also sleep the thread as Adam mentioned.

There are two other issues I am seeing.  You are manipulating state directly.  Since state changes are batched, when you set state it could be overridden by a setState call.  This could lead to data being changed when it should not be.  If you slice your array, you will not be manipulating state directly.

```
var array = this.state.array.slice();
```

The second issue I notice is that you are using a random key value.  This will cause issues with rendering animations, especially if you are using LayoutAnimation.  Since the key changes every render the rendering engine will not know that this object should move to this location.  This will be important if you want to have nice bubbling animations.

Comment: I changed the random key value to the index of the value in the array

Comment: The index of the array will change when you sort so that will not work.